# What are the comparative advantages and disadvantages of interpreting regression output using marginal effects vs. ratios?

Tags: regression-coefficients, nonlinear-regression, odds-ratio, marginal-effect, incidence-rate-ratio

In models with a discrete dependent variable and/or linear models with non-linear right-hand specifications (interactions, polynomials, etc.), interpreting the association between Y and BX becomes much less straightforward. In a standard OLS setup, the OLS coefficient represents the marginal effect, whereas in non-linear models, neither coefficients nor some ratio (odds ratios, IRRs, hazard ratios, etc.) represent the marginal effect that researchers often are substantively interested in. Instead, marginal effects must be calculated as a separate step within the analysis.

While reading [Hanmer and Kalkan 2012](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1111/j.1540-5907.2012.00602.x), I noticed that they limited their commentary largely to the problems of *coefficients* in non-linear models. In particular, they state,

> The issues discussed here do not arise if one interprets the results as odds ratios. However, we find odds ratios to be less informative because on their own they do not reveal anything about the initial probability of success, a necessary element for determining substantive significance. (p. 265).

Because of this, my question is threefold. First, can anyone elaborate on what the authors mean when they state that odds ratios are less informative because they reveal little about initial probability of success? How does this compare with marginal effects?

Is this issue equally a problem with IRRs and hazard ratios?

On a broader scale, what are comparative advantages of marginal effects v. ratios? I think this is an important question for me to understand because of the literature strongly pushing for marginal effects somewhat contrasting with other literatures I am familiar with where ratios are the standard. I would like to know the trade-offs between the two.

Comment: Edward Norton (the economist, not the actor) gave [a very nice talk](https://www.hsrd.research.va.gov/for_researchers/cyber_seminars/archives/video_archive.cfm?SessionID=3823) that addresses most of your questions in the context of a logit model. There is a video, handout (with references), and a transcript at that link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say I'm running a model to predict getting a job (so the dependent variable is 1 for people who have a job and 0 for those who do not). Let's say that I have one independent variable that I really care about - attending a job training program - and a bunch of control variables. The model gives me a coefficient for the job training variable, which is positive and significant. This tells me that, holding all other variables constant, attending the training program is associated with a higher probability of having a job. But HOW much higher?

The coefficient, as you note, doesn't help me answer this question. But neither does transforming it into an odds ratio. An odds ratio tells me how much the "odds" of having a job change, but we want to know how the PROBABILITY changes, and odds and probabilities are different things (the odds of Y are the probability of Y divided by the probability of not-Y).

This is a problem because often when you report odds ratios people will *think* you are reporting "risk ratios" how the probability of Y changes. [But an odds ratio will always be an overestimate of the size of the risk ratio, sometimes by a lot.](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/18580722/) This is one major reason why odds ratios are discouraged - they aren't that interpretable but people often think they are.

Average marginal effects are ONE way of answering the question that people actually care about - how much the probability of the outcome changes. In this case, the AME tells you the "risk difference" - that the probability of getting a job increased by X *percentage points.*  You could also hold the control variables at mean or modal values, calculate the predicted probability for similar cases who did and didn't get the treatment and divide those two numbers to get a risk ratio.

The downside of these approaches, AMEs and predicted probabilities, is that you have to calculate them separately, and you have to make some choice about what to hold all the other covariates at, and that choice will impact the result. This is just a consequence of dealing with probabilities, since they are bounded between 0 and 1.

This is NOT an issue with IRRs or hazard ratios however. The Cox and negative binomial models are not nonlinear in the same way as a logit model, so these ratios can be interpreted as changes in the thing you actually care about: the hazard ratio or rate.